# Recurring quarterly query with Excel email attachment using Business Intelligence Dev studio

Tags: reporting-services, email-attachments, subscription, bids

This is my the first time creating a reporting service. I have a query that i need to set to run on a quarterly subscription, when it finishes the query it needs to send an Excel file by email. I was pointed to use BIDS to create the RS report, i found a web site that uses a query to produce an excel file and send it through. ([Send-Excel-Attachment-Using-SSIS](http://www.devtechie.com/post/2012/01/07/Send-Excel-Attachment-Using-SSIS.aspx))
It uses the Integration Services Template. So far it looks like it should do what it says, however i cannot find a way to set up a subscription.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, set the subscription using SSMS.

Upload the package to your SQL Integration Server, then use SSMS to create a job under the SQL Server Agent.
On the job itself, create the step to fire the SSIS package that you uploaded, and set the frequency to quarterly.

You will need to ensure that the credentials you select have access to all the paths referenced in your SSIS package.

For more information, see:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440761(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I'm marking this answer as accepted because i believe this would work fine however i decided that an Integration Service was not what i needed. Instead i created a standard Reporting Services report and deployed it to the SSRS reporting server and created a subscription that emailed an excel file through that service, very easy. Thank you for the response Eric.